# MongoDB query in PHP: why use $and?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB for the first time and am a little confused about writing queries with multiple arguments.

Considering the following temp collection

```
$col = (new MongoClient())->selectDB('tmpDB')->selectCollection('tmpCol');

$colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'orange', 'purple', 'gray'];
$objects = ['lamps', 'flowers', 'balloons', 'french horns', 'gables', 'slips', 'flamingos', 'streets'];

for ($i=0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    $collection->insert([
        'count' => mt_rand(1, 99),
        'color' => $colors[mt_rand(0, count($colors)-1)],
        'object' => $objects[mt_rand(0, count($objects)-1)],
    ]);
}
```

I want to write a query that will find all of the documents with *red balloons*.  I've read over the MongoDB core docs and come up with two queries:

```
$col->count(['color' => 'red', 'object' => 'balloons']);
```

or

```
$col->count(['$and' => [['color' => 'red'], ['object' => 'balloons']]]);
```

Both queries seem to work. Acknowledging that my data-set is fairly small, both queries return the correct result in roughly the same time.  I'm not sure if there is a difference that I am missing, or if these statements are actually equivalent?  What is the best practice?

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.  If you want to add this as an answer I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case they are equivalent. `$and` on top level is implied. For examples where it's meant to be used, see the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and.

Answer (score 1):

There is slight difference between `$and` and `,` separated list of fields.
MongoDB provides implicit and between all fields separated by `,`. The explicit `$and` is used when you want to same field multiple times in query.